# Try_casting a Sql_variant column truncating the value after a comma

Tags: sql, sql-variant

I have a column 'Value' of sql_variant type. It has the value

```
'Device Warning: Bus Transient, Warning Code: 164, Timestamp: 2015-12-23 13:02:48.750'
```

If I try to select

```
TRY_CAST([Value] AS nvarchar) as varvalue
```

I get the value

```
Device Warning: Bus Transient,
```

How can we cast a sql_variant type without losing some data? I needed to convert it into a nvarchar because I need to use a SUBSTING function to extract parts of the value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: well, just try giving an actual length to your `nvarchar`: `TRY_CAST([Value] AS nvarchar(2000)) as varvalue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)
>
> **Remarks**
>   When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. **When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30**.

```
1> select len('Device Warning: Bus Transient,')
2> go

-----------
         30
```

Specify a length.

QED

Comment: nice, didn't think of going to documentation